# Identifying/remembering project about speculative evolution on another planet

Tags: aliens, space, science, biology, evolution

Another specbio/specevo related question, though not so much about SF/F proper but a real world project

As a kid I had a copy of the Dorling-Kindersley book 'Universe: The Definitive Visual Guide' published in 2005. This was specifically the first edition, which had a cover like this:

[image]

It is specifically this version, because later versions (with different covers) omit the detail, but in the chapter on the search for extra-terrestrial life (SETI, etc), it mentions off-hand in a corner about this scientific university project (I believe Cambridge was one of the universities involved?) simulating life on other worlds, a speculative evolution project. The project had 'created' (fictionally) an alien creature which looked like a cross between an armadillo and a lobster, but blue, and it had a cutesy name too, this included a picture of it as well, how I remember it.

I keep trying to find this project again, to remember what the 'alien' looked like, but I cant as the only copies of the Dorling Kindersley book I can find online are later ones, that omit it. If anyone could help either identify the experiment/project or find it from the original first edition, that would be a great help!

Comment: Maybe the [Coti simulation](https://www.contact-conference.org/c00b.html)? I don't know what book it could have appeared in though.

Comment: Ah, this isn't the exact one either, or at the least I dont see the creature I remember here. This is a fascinating project though.

Again thats why I named the book I remember it in, as it was definitely there, if someone has that first edition (for added context, I live in the UK) it would be able to find it hopefully

Comment: Hmm, if no one here has a copy of that book or recognizes the description, it looks like you can get a copy of that edition pretty cheap from some of the [listings from UK sellers on bookfinder.com](https://www.bookfinder.com/search/?author=&title=&lang=en&new_used=*&destination=gb&currency=GBP&binding=*&isbn=1405316403&keywords=&minprice=&maxprice=&publisher=&min_year=&max_year=&mode=advanced&st=sr&ac=qr) (if you or anyone else does pick it up, be sure to post the answer!)

Comment: Hm, if nobody does eventually answer I may have to do just that, honestly.

Comment: Also, I have asked this question on Reddit as well (the SpeculativeEvolution subreddit) and someone replied with this creature that feels very, very similar to the one I remember - all thats diff is colour, mostly: https://i.imgur.com/kB5BZuA.jpeg

However - this is apparently from Dougal Dixon's Greenworld, which was published in 2010, but the Universe book was published in 2005? This is getting so strange...

Answer (score 1):

Possibly the [Medea project](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medea:_Harlan%27s_World)

> Medea: Harlan's World (1985; ISBN 0-932096-36-0) is a 1985 collection
> of science fiction short stories by different authors, all taking
> place on the same fictional moon. It was an experiment in
> collaborative science fictional world-building, featuring
> contributions by Hal Clement, Frank Herbert, and others.

[More details](https://www.librarything.com/work/199354)

> Medea was an epic project. Harlan Ellison decided it would be a good
> idea to bring together some of the best science fiction writers
> available and allow them to build a world in front of an audience. He
> accomplished it in 1975 where a stageful of science fiction authors,
> in front of a group of college students numbered in the thousands,
> dreamed and fleshed out the world “Medea” (or, as it became
> affectionately known, “Harlan’s World”)

Comment: Ah, sadly not at all - again, if I remember correctly, this was a full on scientific project being done at universities (I believe Cambridge involvement?), not an explicit science-fiction project like this.

Comment: Sorry - I'll keep searching.

Comment: No worries! I haven't heard of this project before and I LOVE the Frank Kelly Freas art for it, so thanks for bringing it to my attention anyway!